# Package class override in maven project dependency, what is this behavior called?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I have a **dependency project** where I define following class

```
package it.dependency.common;

public class Consumer {
    public void consume() {
        Worker dependency = new Worker();
        dependency.work();
    }
}
```

and

```
package it.dependency.common;

public class Worker {
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("I'm doing things in the DEPENDENCY project");
    }
}
```

If I run a simple main that call the mathod `consume()` of the Consumer object it prints correctly *I'm doing things in the DEPENDENCY project*.

I compile this maven project into a jar and I import it in a other project as a dependency in a other project called **test project**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <systemPath>${lib.path}/dependency-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I can redefine an other class like

```
package it.dependency.common;

public class Worker {
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("I'm doing things in the TEST project");
    }
}
```

Now, if I run a simple main where I call the Consumer class of the DEPENDENCY project it prints *I'm doing things in the TEST project*.

So the consumer actually uses the Worker class of a project that it don't know. Like an override package class?
How it works this behavior and how it is called?

Answer (score 0):

This is a dependency injection only, you are able to access the child project(dependency) functionalities in your Test Project as long as it is in your classpath.

In your case, I see both Worker class is on the same package?

Comment: Exactly. They have the same class Worker in the same project , but the MAIN project calls the Consumer class of the dependency project which in theory calls inside the worker of the dependency